# Set html width as width minus scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I'm having issues with a site where the scroll bars is disabled by various modals, causing the site percentages to change when modals are active.

How can I code the site to generate the entire layout using the `html` width without the scrollbar? Then, when the modal is active, no CSS recalculation will take place.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        $(function() {
            $("html").css({
            "width": outerWidth()
          });
        });
```

But something is wrong with the syntax I think…

Answer (score 1):

Use `.outerWidth()` to include the width of the scrollbar:

```
$('body').innerWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell jQuery what you want to have the `outerWidth()` of. In this Case we can use `$(this)` because you already `$("html")` in the line above.

```
$(function() {
    $("html").css({
        "width": $(this).outerWidth()
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but the `position: fixed` elements still calculate a CSS percentage from the screen size, not the `html` width. How can I force fixed position elements to get the parent size from the `html` element? @NoahWetjen

Comment: @univers_ Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show what exactly you mean, because I think I don't get your point?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p88Rt/3/ Notice the header element changing width on modal open. Perhaps I can define header with using jQuery? @NoahWetjen

Comment: @univers_ But you still want the Scrollbar to go away, or would it be okay if it just stayed there?

Comment: The priority is for background scrolling on the `html` element to go away when the modal is active. @NoahWetjen

Answer (score 0):

The `innerWidth` of `body` does not include the width of scrollbar, but `outerWidth` does:

```
$('body').innerWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution…

http://jsfiddle.net/p88Rt/4/

I defined a wrapper for the header with 100% of `outerWidth`, then position a relative element inside it. It would be cleaner to have no wrapper and definite the width of the header using maths (80% * `outerWidth`) but not sure of the jQuery syntax.

```
$(function() {
$("html").css({
    "width": $(this).outerWidth()
});
$("#header-outer").css({
    "width": $(this).outerWidth()
});
```